# Is frequency$\times$(time period) = 1 unit?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, dimensional-analysis, oscillators

In my book, I have read that the frequency of sound is inversely proportional to the time period i.e., $1/T =  \nu$. So does that mean 
$$\text{frequency} \times \text{time period} =1$$
i.e., is $\nu \,T = 1$ unit??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The frequency of $\nu$ of any monochromatic wave is **defined** as $\nu=1/T$, so that $\nu \, T\equiv 1$ is an identity by definition.

---

As for the initial version of your question: the product of the speed of sound $c$ and the period $T$ of a (monochromatic) wave is
$$
c \, T = \lambda,
$$
the **wavelength** of the wave.

The fact that a quantity $a$ is "inversely proportional to" some other quantity $b$, denoted $a\propto 1/b$, means that there exists some constant $k$ such that $a=k/b$, *not* that $a=1/b$ with that constant equal to unity. Moreover, if the product $ab$ is not dimensionless (like the product $cT$, a speed times a time, which gives a length) it is completely impossible for that constant to be unity or any other dimensionless number.

Comment: Actually I meant frequency* time period.

Comment: @AnkitBehera Then have a downvote for posting before checking your post.

Comment: I admit that I hadn't checked before posting but please answer my question